# bus company using only arithmetics

Tags: java

My homework assignment is: I run a bus company and I need to know how many buses need to be used, based on the number of seats in a bus and the number of passengers. For example: if I have 17 passengers and a 3 seat bus, I have to use 6 buses. 5 buses for the first 15 people and another one for the 2 remaining.

I cant use for loops, if statements, or recursion, only arithmetic.

This is my pseudo code but it's wrong:

```
    numbus=numOfPeople / seat;
    remain=numOfPeople % seat; 
    temp=numOfBus % remain;
    orderBus=numbus+temp;
    System.out.println(orderbus);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it's wrong"?

Comment: line `temp=numOfBus % remain;` does not make any sense, you should use `Math.ceil((double)numOfPeople / seat)` to calculate number of buses

Comment: What is `numOfBus`? It is undefined in the scope of the question. Prehaps you mean `numbus`, as defined in the first line?

Comment: @bcsb1001 yes, I've updated comment already, refresh the page

Comment: @John Marrelly Take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is: in order to calculate the remain:

```
remain = numOfPeople % numbus
```

And finally:

```
orderBus = numbus + (remain > 0 ? 1 : 0)  // an additional bus if the remain > 0
```

Complete code:

```
numbus = numOfPeople / seat;
remain = numOfPeople % numbus;
orderBus = numbus + (remain > 0 ? 1 : 0);
// in case you can't use ternary form:
// orderBus = numbus + (remain ^ 0)
System.out.println(orderbus);
```

Comment: I disagree with this. If we have 5 people, and busses with 3 person capacity, your solution says we need to order 3 busses. (1 full + (remainder 2)).

Comment: I was going to post a solution using ternary as well, but does this count as an if statement which OP says he can not use?

Comment: @MattClark good question, the OP didn't specify else so I didn't assume it's not a valid answer. I'll let the OP respond. (it can also be calculated by doing `remain ^ 0` but I rather not get into it unless necessary).

Comment: no i cant use ternary neither function such as math or anything like that. only basic arithmetics....

Comment: As I a commented, you can replace `(remain > 0 ? 1 : 0);` with `(remain^0)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you were given a strict requirement on no loops and ifs, you probably can't use ternary operator as well. In fact, you don't need those.

**It can be as simple as:**

```
System.out.println(Math.ceil(passengers/seat));
```

---

For example `(Math.ceil(17/3.0));` gives you `6.0`. What you need is to get the quotient by dividing **passengers** with **seats**. If the quotient is not a whole number, always round it up by one. This is achieved by using `Math.ceil()`.

So if there are remainders, you round up to 1 (1 more bus to ferry the rest of the passengers)

Comment: The OP wrote in the comments that he can't use math lib